# Graph only uses one array values for y values, but not x values

Tags: vba, charts

When the code creates the chart it only takes on the y values (finalflows).

> The x values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 rather than the value of my array flows

```
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If



ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter, Left:=20, Width:=360, Height:=300, Top:=252).Select
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Tubing Performance Curve"
        .ChartTitle.Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "FlowRate(MCF/Day)"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Welbore Flowing Pressure (psia)"
        .HasLegend = False
    End With

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = flows
    .Values = finalflow
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 225)
    .Format.Line.Weight = 2
    .HasDataLabels = True
End With
```

Comment: When you go through your code step by step, what line does not do what you want it to do?

Comment: do you actually have an array named _flows_ ?

Comment: I have two arrays: flows and finalflow. The code above is supposed to use one for the x-axis (flows) and y-axis (finalflows). but only the final flows are being graphed

Comment: what kind of array is it ? one dimensional or?